# is there any way to customize the encoding used by OpenAM agent to put headers?

Tags: apache, security, encoding, openam

I have an enterprise OpenAM installation, which is used with the Apache front-end of my application to push credentials as HTTP headers. These headers contain

- user name
- user login
- user email

As application is used in France, I've discovered that users with 'é' or 'è' in names have these characters replaced by weird badly encoded versions of these characters.

To fix that, I think the two most obvious places are my application, and the Apache configuration. However, as we plan to use this Apache instance as an auth front-end for all applications installed on that machine, I would prefer to change Apache configuration. So, where is OpenAM Apache agent configuration stored ? And is there any configuration property that changes the encoding used to send data to applications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the version of OpenAM, but usually agent configuration is centralized on the OpenAM server. The agent settings will be under realm -> Agents -> agent name.  You should first verify the characters look correct in the ldap profile store.